# Nativescript debug failed to install package

Tags: nativescript

I'm using an Ubuntu Linux workstation to learn and develop Nativescript apps.  I can use 'tns build android' to create a package and then copy the apk to the device without issue. If I try 'tns debug android', 'tns deploy android', or 'tns run i get the following

> Project successfully prepared (android) Installing on device
>   988dd2483731455242... Unable to apply changes on device:
>   988dd2483731455242. Error is: The system failed to install the package
>   because of system issues..

I'm running Nativescript 6.3.3.

Anyone have any ideas or can you point me to a document that might tell me what permissions, etc. are required on Android to fix the "system issues"?

Comment: If you had used tns build then you must have used your certificate to sign the APK. Now when you use tns run / debug it may try to install an unsigned APK or one signed with a default debug certificate. Now your device will not be able to handle it as there is a conflict between certificates used for same package. Try to uninstall the app, sometimes even after uninstall you may have to go to all apps in settings and remove it completely or use adb uninstall command. Then your run / debug should work

Comment: I'm not using any certificates -- at least as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to the Samsung Knox and BlackBerry UEM Client.  I did a factory reset on the phone (after getting a new phone) and after enabling developer options and USB debugging I can now use tns run and tns debug.  On the new phone, I have the same issue.  Still tying to figure out what settings are required through.

Oh, Google Play now tries to prevent this but it's easy to get around.